# Calculate the limit or prove it doesn't exist: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{1/\cos(x) - 1}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

This is the limit:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{\frac{1}{\cos(x)} - 1}\ $$

Now I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use arithmetic of limits, as I don't know if the limit exist.
I don't understand why I can't just say that:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x) = 0 $$ and therefore the upper limit is also 0 (regardless of the denominator..

Thank you

Comment: why don't you try to use your idea on a function that satisfies $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$?

Comment: The denominator limits to 0 so the arithmetic of limits doesn't (immediately) apply.

Comment: The reason why you cannot say that, is because even when the numerator tends to zero, if the denominator also tends to zero, and does so "just as fast or even faster", the denominator will "win" and the limit of the full expression could fail to be zero. Simple example: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 10):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{\frac1{\cos(x)}-1}=\frac{\frac12\sin(2x)}{1-\cos(x)}=\frac{\frac12\sin(2x)}{2\sin^2(x/2)}\sim \frac{x}{x^2/2}$$

Answer (score 6):

Write as 
$$\cos x\frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{x^2}{1-\cos x}\frac{1}{x}$$
All factors have a finite limit except the last, which as limit $\infty$, so it does not exist.

Comment: That last sentence needs work. "Finite" is not enough. You want to say "finite non-zero limit" Also, the limit is $-\infty$ from the left.

Comment: I can't see why 1 - cos(x) isn't a problem.. cox(x) when x->0 is 1 so don't we need to keep simplifying it?

Comment: $\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\to\frac{1}{2}$ is a well known limit.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

$${\sin x\over{1\over\cos x}-1}={\sin x\cos x\over1-\cos x}={\sin x\cos x (1+\cos x)\over1-\cos^2x}={\cos x(1+\cos x)\over\sin x}$$

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I still can't see it.. you have sinx in the denominator so you still can't use arithmetic of limits..

Comment: @Noam, does Mark Bennet's answer make any more sense to you?  Or Dr. MV's hint?  We're all saying pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @Noam - note that this is no longer an indeterminant form. By Barry's work, the form is $\frac 2 0$. You can say something about that limit. If your limit converges, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{\frac{1}{\cos x} - 1} = L$, then $2 = \lim_{x\to 0} \cos x(1+\cos x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \sin x \frac{\sin x}{\frac{1}{\cos x} - 1} = 0 \cdot L = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply through by $\cos x$ $(\text{NB }\neq 0)$ to clear fractions and obtain $$\frac {\sin x\cos x}{1-\cos x}=\frac {2\sin {\frac x2}\cos {\frac x2}\cos x}{2\sin^2 {\frac x2}}=\frac {\cos {\frac x2}\cos x}{\sin {\frac x2}}$$And now the behaviour should be obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac xx=1$$

This should be fairly obvious since $x/x=1$.

But by your logic, this limit should be $0$.

But you forget that the denominator is also $0$, so it is actually an indeterminate form.  If the denominator were anything else, then your reasoning would be right.

You should look towards the other answers to find more suitable methods for evaluating these types of limits.

Comment: I understand, thank you.

Comment: @Noam No problem, just be careful with the way you handle limits.