# Calculate limit with floor function or prove it doesnt exist

Tags: limits, trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Please help calculating the following limit:

$$  \lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\lfloor{}\sin(x)\rfloor}{\lfloor x\rfloor}  $$

I used $$ t = x - \frac{\pi}{2} $$ and got:

$$  \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\lfloor{}\sin(t+\frac{\pi}{2})\rfloor}{\lfloor t+\frac{\pi}{2}\rfloor}  $$

for t close to 0 we get from arithmetic of limits that the denominator is 1 but not sure how to go from here..

Thanks

Comment: You've asked another one of these recently, without accepting an answer there. If you found an answer the most helpful, please accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076532

Comment: @TheGreatDuck That doesn't uniquely define a post :)

Answer (score 2):

The floor function is continuous on $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Z$ so 
$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2}\lfloor x\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac\pi2\right\rfloor=1$$
and since

$$0\le \sin x<1\,\forall x\in I:=(0,\pi)\setminus\{\frac\pi2\}$$
hence $\lfloor \sin x\rfloor=0\;\forall x\in I$ so the desired limit is $0$.

Comment: The limit at a point has nothing to do with the value of the function at the point.

Comment: No the limit of continuous function at a point is exactly its value in this point.

Comment: @ user296113: Right your comment and right the mine one.

Answer (score 1):

In the range $\left(1,\pi\right)$ but at $\pi/2$, as the numerator is zero and the denominator nonzero, the function is zero.

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$\forall x\in(0,\pi)\;\; 0<\sin(x)<1 $ and $\lfloor \sin(x) \rfloor =0$.

the limit is zero.

Answer (score -1):

In a punctured neighborhood of $\pi/2$ we have $\lfloor\sin x\rfloor=0$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor=\color{red}1$, so the limit is $0$.

Comment: $\lfloor x\rfloor=3$ ???

Comment: Do you imagine what is a typo? :)